# Como realizar login em um sistema por meio de uma requisição HTTP?

Tags: java, http-request, autenticação-http

Estou realizando uma requisição HTTPS get para o [seguinte endereço](https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/), a minha intenção inicial é receber os dados html da página. Segui o tutorial do [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/), mas recebo o código de resposta 302, não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, adicionei os *headers* necessários, mas mesmo assim não estou recebendo um resultado positivo.
Segue o código:

```
public class HttpUrlConnectionUFAC {

    private List<String> cookies;
    private HttpsURLConnection conn;

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/login/";

        HttpUrlConnectionUFAC http = new HttpUrlConnectionUFAC();

        // make sure cookies is turn on
        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

        // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
        String page = null;
        try {
            page = http.getPageContent(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Resposta:\n"+page);
    }

    private String getPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // default is GET
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        // Acts like a browser
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Remote Address",
                "200.129.173.7:443");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding",
                "gzip, deflate, sdch");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "portal.ufac.br");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/login.action?error=");

        if (cookies != null) {
            for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
                conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
            }
        }
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // Get the response cookies
        setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

        return response.toString();

    }



    public List<String> getCookies() {
        return cookies;
    }

    public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
        this.cookies = cookies;
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
Sending 'GET' request to URL : https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/login/
Response Code : 302
Resposta:
‹
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Como posso realizar corretamente essa requisição?

Comment: @re22 minha ideia inicial é recuperar o código html, depois realizar a autenticação nesse site, mas nem recuperar o código estou conseguindo.

Comment: Imprime os cabeçalhos da resposta. Deve ter um header location com o endereco para o request  (adicionalmente eu arrancaria boa parte dos headers de request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problema solucionado! Utilizei a ferramenta **HtmlUnit** sugerida por @re22 e conseguí recuperar as informações do site.

Primeiro criei um objeto WebClient que simula o navegador Chrome, depois criei um CookieManager para gerenciar os dados da sessão, para poder realizar várias requisições após a autenticação no site.

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
CookieManager cookieMan = new CookieManager();
cookieMan = webClient.getCookieManager();
cookieMan.setCookiesEnabled(true);
```

Utilizei esses dois métodos para desabilitar mensagens de advertências relacionadas aos documentos html recebidos ao realizar as requisições:

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
```

Nesse trecho capturo a página de login, seus formulários, no caso apenas 1, concatenado-os em um único formulário html, onde adiciono as informações para realizar o login nos campos *j_password* e *j_username*:

```
    pagina = webClient.getPage("https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/login.action");

    List<HtmlForm> formularios = pagina.getForms();
    HtmlForm formulario = null;

    for (HtmlForm htmlForm : formularios) {
        formulario = htmlForm;
    }
    HtmlTextInput usuario = formulario.getInputByName("j_username");
    HtmlPasswordInput senha = formulario.getInputByName("j_password");              
    usuario.setValueAttribute("******");
    senha.setValueAttribute("******");
```

Por fim crio uma página html de resposta simulando um clique em um botão, depois utilizando esse html faço uma requisição web para obter os dados da sessão, sendo autenticado é armazenado pelo CookieManager duas sessões, caso contrários será armazenada uma única sessão. Depois fiz uma requisição para recuperar o conteúdo da página de perfil do usuário após a autenticação no site.

```
final HtmlPage paginaResposta = (HtmlPage) formulario.getInputByValue("Entrar").click();
paginaResposta.getWebResponse();
String result = webClient.getPage("https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/aluno/perfil/perfil.action").getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Segue abaixo a implementação completa:

```
    //Cria o cliente
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    //O CookieManager vai gerenciar os dados da sessão
    CookieManager cookieMan = new CookieManager();
    cookieMan = webClient.getCookieManager();
    cookieMan.setCookiesEnabled(true);

    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

    HtmlPage pagina;
    try {
        pagina = webClient.getPage("https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/login.action");


        List<HtmlForm> formularios = pagina.getForms();
        HtmlForm formulario = null;

        for (HtmlForm htmlForm : formularios) {
            formulario = htmlForm;
        }

        HtmlTextInput usuario = formulario.getInputByName("j_username");
        HtmlPasswordInput senha = formulario.getInputByName("j_password");              
        usuario.setValueAttribute("******");
        senha.setValueAttribute("******");

        final HtmlPage paginaResposta = (HtmlPage) formulario.getInputByValue("Entrar").click();
        paginaResposta.getWebResponse();

        //Navegando para a página de perfil do usuário
        String result = webClient.getPage("https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/aluno/perfil/perfil.action").getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
        System.out.println("RESULT:\n "+ result); 
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(cookieMan.getCookies());
```

Comment: Se precisar somente do texto (não do código todo), pode fazer: `String texto = webClient.getPage("foo.com").asText();`.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [**Jsoup**](http://jsoup.org/). Para obter o código html de uma página basta:

```
Document document =  Jsoup.connect("http://pt.stackoverflow.com").get();
System.out.println(document.html()); // html da página
```

No seu caso, parece que está querendo mais que o código html. Como o usuário deve ser autenticado, provavelmente deve existir um *cookie* que mantém a sessão para as próximas requisições, pode obtê-lo assim:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/")
          .data("j_username", "joaoDaSilva", "j_password", "joao1234")
          .method(Connection.Method.POST)
          .execute();

String theHtml = response.parse().html(); // html
Map<String, String> theCookies = response.cookies(); // obtém os cookies
```

E nas próximas requisições:

```
Document randomPage = Jsoup.connect("https://portal.ufac/foo")
         .cookies(theCookies)
         .get();

System.out.println(randomPage.html()); // html da página.
```

---

Se precisa de algo mais completo, uma alternativa é o [**HtmlUnit**](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). [Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69880/4808) há uma explicação mínima e um exemplo de como acessar, preencher e enviar um formulário de login em uma página web.

Comment: O "foo" dentro da String do Jsoup.connect("https://portal.ufac/foo") seria a o local da página index após o login? Tentei dessa forma e apenas recebí o código da página de autenticação, como se eu não tivesse sido autenticado no site...

Comment: continuo recebendo o conteúdo da página de login... Analisando o conteúdo encontrei isso: <div id="no-script">
    O JavaScript está desativado ou não é suportado pelo seu navegador. Para usar o Portal do Aluno adequadamente, ative o JavaScript alterando as opções do navegador e tente novamente.
   </div> .. Poderia ser esse o problema? Se sim, como faço para ativar o JS nessa requisição? obrigado

Comment: tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: conseguí realizar a requisição HTTP com sucesso utilizando o HtmlUnit, editei minha pergunta com a solução que utilizei usando a feramenta que você me sugeriu. Muito Obrigado.