# Como funciona o HtmlUnit?

Tags: javascript, java, java-ee, aplicação-web

Alguém tem algum exemplo de login de um sistema web comunicando com outro, onde eu irei enviar o usuário e a senha pra outro site e esse site fará a autenticação e me dará um retorno se o usuário e senha estão corretos ou não, utilizando HtmlUnit em java.

Exemplo do que farei:
Tenho um sistema web que para logar quero utilizar outro sistema que o cliente, que é o mesmo, preferiu não dar acesso ao Banco de Dados desse outro sistema, assim tenho uma página de login, onde o usuário coloca o login e senha e através do HtmlUnit, eu envio ao outro sistema, em forma de requisição, essas informações, e assim obtenho uma pagina com javascript, como resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em resumo, o [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) possui uma API que permite aplicações Java executarem as mesmas ações que um usuário realizaria no navegador, alguns exemplos incluem invocar uma página web, clicar em botões e/ou links, preencher formulários...

A grosso modo é um navegador sem a interface gráfica ─ *os responsáveis pelo projeto o intitulam assim* ─ as [*features*](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/#Features) e outras informações podem ser encontradas na página do projeto.

## Exemplo

Considere um acesso à página `http://meusiteficticio.com` que possui um formulário na página com essa estrutura:

```
<form id='form-login' action='/login' method='post'>
   <input name='user' type='text' placeholder='Nome de usuário'/>
   <input name='pass' type='password' placeholder='Senha'/>
   <input type='submit' value='entrar'/>
</form>
```

Pelo navegador, o usuário iria inserir um nome de usuário e uma senha nos devidos campos, em seguida clicar no botão para submeter o formulário. Nós, faremos o mesmo porém dentro da aplicação.

Eles implementaram ([v2.8](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html#a2.8)) e tornaram público ([v2.11](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html#a2.11)) os métodos `querySelector` e `querySelectorAll` que funcionam semelhante as funções que existem em Javascript. Para obter o mesmo resultado do código anterior com estes métodos o código pode ficar assim:

```
// Obtém a página de login.
HtmlPage paginaDeLogin = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED)
                             .getPage("http://meusiteficticio.com");

// Obtém os elementos do formulário.
HtmlTextInput inputNomeDeUsuario = paginaDeLogin.querySelector("input[name='user']");
HtmlPasswordInput inputSenha = paginaDeLogin.querySelector("input[name='pass']");
HtmlSubmitInput botaoEnviar = paginaDeLogin.querySelector("#form-login > input[type='submit']");

// Define o valor do atributo 'value' dos inputs.
inputNomeDeUsuario.setValueAttribute("joao");
inputSenha.setValueAttribute("joao1234");

// Simula o "click" no botão de submit e aguarda retorno
HtmlPage paginaAposOLogin = botaoEnviar.click();

// Mostra o código html da página
System.out.println(paginaAposOLogin.asXml());
```

Se estiver usando uma versão antiga, que não suporta o `querySelector`, você primeiro terá que obter o formulário e depois ir pegando os inputs por meio do método `getInputByName`:

```
// Simulando um navegador Chrome.
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

// Obtém a página.
HtmlPage paginaDeLogin = client.getPage("http://meusiteficticio.com");

// Obtém o formulário de login pelo atributo "id" no html.
// O segundo parâmetro é para aceitar case-sensitive
// e.g "FoRm-LoGiN" também encontraria o formulário.
HtmlForm formularioDeLogin = paginaDeLogin.getElementById("form-login", true);

// Obtém o inputs (do formulário) pelo atributo "name":
HtmlTextInput inputNomeDeUsuario = formularioDeLogin.getInputByName("user");
HtmlPasswordInput inputSenha = formularioDeLogin.getInputByName("pass");

// O "botão" de submit não possui name, id, class, etc.
// Então uma forma de obtê-lo é pelo "value='entrar".
HtmlSubmitInput botaoEnviar = formularioDeLogin.getInputByValue("entrar");

// Insere os valores nos campos de nome de usuário e senha
// (como se estivesse digitando pelo navegador)
inputNomeDeUsuario.setValueAttribute("joao");
inputSenha.setValueAttribute("joao1234");

// Simula o "click" no botão de submit e aguarda retorno
HtmlPage paginaAposOLogin = botaoEnviar.click();

// Mostra o código html da página
System.out.println(paginaAposOLogin.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());
```

Seja legal, trate as exceções. Tentar inserir (ou mesmo manipular) um valor em um input que não existe lançará uma [**`NullPointerException`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/4808).

#### Mantendo os *cookies*

Se precisar manter os *cookies* para o uso nas próximas requisições você deve definir um [**`CookieManager`**](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/CookieManager.html) para o seu "navegador" ─ leia-se [**`WebClient`**](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html).

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
CookieManager cookieManager = client.getCookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiesEnabled(true);
client.setCookieManager(cookieManager);

HtmlPage fb = client.getPage("https://facebook.com");
```

#### Desabilitando avisos e Advertências

O HtmlUnit irá exibir todas as advertências que invalide o documento Html, por exemplo, atributos obsoletos, erros em código Javascript e CSS ─ como pode ser visto nessa imagem:

<kbd>[image: Exemplo]</kbd>

Você pode desligar esses alertas definindo nível do logger do HtmlUnit como `OFF`:

```
Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```